# Calculate a row order after DELETE

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-delete

I'm using phonegap to make an ios and android app.
I am using WebSql and I'm facing this problem : 
I want to rearange the value of a column named 'position' when you delete any row.
Eg. : 
The base table is :

```
╔═════╦══════════╗
║ ID  ║ POSITION ║
╠═════╬══════════╣
║  23 ║        0 ║
║  32 ║        1 ║
║ 143 ║        2 ║
║  13 ║        3 ║
╚═════╩══════════╝
```

If I want to delete for example the row that have the position : 1, the position of the rows under automatically decrease by one like :

```
╔═════╦══════════╗
║ ID  ║ POSITION ║
╠═════╬══════════╣
║  23 ║        0 ║
║ 143 ║        1 ║
║  13 ║        2 ║
╚═════╩══════════╝
```

My question is : Is there a way to do this directly in MySql after a row deletion ? 
or do I need to do this in javascript like :
 - Delete my row
 - Query all the table
 - Loop on them to change their position
 - Update the rows.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally for my case, using localStorage was easier and better than WebSql.

Answer (score 2):

after the delete statement has been executed, run this update statement to modify the values of the `position`

```
UPDATE  tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.id, @rn := @rn + 1 New_position
            FROM    tableName a, (SELECT @rn := 0) b
            ORDER   BY a.Position
        ) b ON  a.ID = b.ID
SET     a.Position = b.New_Position
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e3b8/1)

This is the OUTPUT after the statement has been executed,

```
╔═════╦══════════╗
║ ID  ║ POSITION ║
╠═════╬══════════╣
║  23 ║        1 ║
║ 143 ║        2 ║
║  13 ║        3 ║
╚═════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: It seems like the 'a' or 'b' variables (referring to tableName) aren't working.
When I do this simple delete statement, I also have an error : 
DELETE FROM FAVOURITES a WHERE a.id = 72104 ;

Comment: your `DELETE` statement has syntax error because you have specified an alias on the table but you did not use it. It should be `DELETE a FROM FAVOURITES a WHERE a.id = 72104`

Comment: have you seen this demo? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e3b8/1 I was wondering why you said that it isn't working..

Comment: Yes I have seen the demo, but it doesn't work when I use it on my Phonegap app. Even the correct DELETE with the alias doesn't work.
I have an 'undefined' error code :/

Comment: what if you execute this? `DELETE FROM FAVOURITES WHERE id = 72104` does it delete the record? if not what is the full error message?

Comment: Yes it does. The alias on the DELETE statement was just to test if the alias works with WebSql but It seems that It doesn't.
I tested this because of the UPDATE statement not working and beause it contains aliases.

Comment: if you execute this one with alias `DELETE a FROM FAVOURITES a WHERE a.id = 72104` what is the full error message?

Comment: error.code and error.message are both undefined ... http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#SQLError